# Accessing object value in knockout

Tags: object, knockout.js

I declare this in knockout:

```
self.quizAnswer = ko.observableArray([{val: ko.observable()}]);
```

I can push the value there:

```
self.quizAnswer.push({ val: ko.observable('new') });
```

But tell me please how to easily read/rewrite the value like:

```
self.quizAnswer()[#position#].val = "new value";
```

I tried almost everything, but I dont know.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because observable is function, you should invoke it without parameter to read its value:

```
self.quizAnswer()[0].val();
```

or with parameter to set new value:

```
self.quizAnswer()[0].val("new value");
```

Another option is to use [knockout-es5](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/) plugin. If you use this plugin you can invoke something like this:

```
ko.track(self.quizAnswer()[0]);
```

and after that you can access all observable of "tracked" objects like regular fields:

```
self.quizAnswer()[0].val = "new value"
```